# How do I convert a CMTime to an NSValue in Swift?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer, cmtime, nsvalue

I was trying to make use of AVPlayer's [`addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes`](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:queue:usingBlock:) method from swift and ran into a problem converting `CMTimes` to `NSValues`, which is what `addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes` take as input. In the end I resorted to wrapping [NSString valueWithCMTime:] in a C function and calling it from swift, but is there a way to do it in pure swift?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Swift constructor corresponding to [valueWithCMTime:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsvalue/1388561-valuewithcmtime?language=objc) is [NSValue(time:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsvalue/1388561-init):

```
import CoreMedia
import AVFoundation

let cmTime  = CMTimeMake(value: 10, timescale: 20) // Updated for Swift 3+
let cmValue = NSValue(time: cmTime)
// Or simply:
let cmValue = cmTime as NSValue
```

Comment: The problem was I wasn't importing CoreMedia. For some reason I thought the CMTime constructor for NSValue was defined in AVFoundation. Thanks!

Comment: For swift 3 have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38669061/nsvaluecmtime-in-swift-3