# NSValue(CMTime: ) in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, swift2, swift3

i have this code

```
  var times = [NSValue]()
        for time in timePoints {
            times.append(NSValue(CMTime : time))
        }
```

i get an error that their is nothing called CMTime in swift 3 i can't really find any param for cm time..

Answer (score 11):

Check [the reference of `NSValue`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsvalue).

> ```
> init(time: CMTime)
> ```

Use `NSValue(time: time)`.

---

One more. If you want to convert `[CMTime]` to `[NSValue]`, you can write something like this:

```
let times = timePoints.map(NSValue.init(time:))
```